# Estou a tentar mover o meu texto para o canto inferior direito mas não consigo

Tags: html

**O meu  código:**

```
<font color="white" align="right">&nbsp;
<br>
Lucas Sintra
</div>
```

Comment: Lucas coloque o código completo do seu HTML e do CSS que está usando também!

Comment: Tenta: `<div align="right">Lucas Sintra</div>`

Comment: Não é recomendado usar a tag `<font>`, está obsoleta e pode ser excluída a qualquer momento dos navegadores. **[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/HTML/Element/font)**

Answer (score 2):

Na sua `<div>` adicione o stributo `style` e a propriedade `text-align: right;`

Deixei o fundo da `<div>` como cinza só para permitir a visualização na resposta.

```html
<div style="background-color:#ccc; text-align: right;">
<font color="white" align="right">
  &nbsp;
  <br>
  Lucas Sintra
</font>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Fiz esse modelinho bem simples só para te ajudar a entender o código, se tiver alguma dúvida e só comentar que te ajudo. ***Clique em Executar para ver funcionando!***

```css
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    }
.texto {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    margin: 0 1rem 1rem 0;
}
.texto p {
    line-height: 0;
    color: red;
    font-size: 2rem;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<div class="texto">
    <p>Lucas Sintra</p>
</div>
```